# Galaxy Nexus (sw360dp) values file

Tags: java, android, layout

The Galaxy Nexus phone layout is set in layout-sw360dp folder. And the files are read from there. The rest read the layout from layout-xhdpi.
But when it comes to, say, phone with 800x400 resolution, and the dimens.xml file, both these phones and the Galaxy Nexus get the values (dimens.xml) from values-xhdpi. And I thought that values/ would be applicable to HDPI devices and values-xhdpi to XHDPI devices such as the Galaxy Nexus.

How can I distinguish the files from values so that one are applicable only to Galaxy Nexus (sw360dp) and other only to smaller-screen/density devices (such as the Nexus S) ?

Thanks

Comment: Note: using resources you won't apply those layouts/values/etc just to Galaxy Nexus. You will apply them to any phone with those characteristics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same mechanisms that work for the layout folder also work for values, i.e. create a `values-sw360dp` folder. See also http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html.